# Laravel queue calls on himself once again, now they are two competing queues

Tags: laravel

I have the problem of two competitive queues.
the first queue will be executed and if a job will be added to the queue, it creates a new instance from the queue.
But now they are two queues which work against each other.

Who could I prevent laravel to create a new queue process?[image]

Supervisor config

```
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php /var/www/releases/current/artisan queue:work --queue=mam 
       --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=30000
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    user=vierol
    numprocs=1
    redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: how are you launching those queue workers?

Comment: It is very difficult for us to help you if you do not share your codes with us.

Comment: Hi 
via supervisor
config from supervisor
`code`
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=vierol
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/root/supervisor_mam/mam_worker.log
`code`
But the option from numprocs is one at the config.
The new process is also a child process from the main queue.
It look like larave creates a new job and not supvervisor.

Comment: @JeyhunRashidov it's difficult to post all the code,
because at I have 8 Jobs who could be added to this specific queue.
Also each of the jobs contains a lot of code lines.